# Integral over a function that evaluates the same integral

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$$x(t) = c + k \int_0^t\int_0^u x(v) \, \mathrm d v \,\mathrm du$$

I need to solve for t such that $x(t) = 0$.

Edit: As an extra clarification, the problem is that the function that is being integrated depends on itself so I can think only of numerical solutions.

**Update**

Now I need a solution for the more general equation:

$$x(t) = c + \int_0^t\int_0^u f(x(v))x(v) \, \mathrm d v \,\mathrm du$$

If there is no solution for a general f(x), the it would be great if someone can tell me for which f(x) (non constant) there is an analytic solution.

Comment: is $\ddot x=kx$ any easier ?

Comment: I think you didn't get the question, perhaps it is not well stated. The integral cannot be solved directly to a primitive, because the function that is being evaluated is itself, x(t). If it instead it was y(t) = integral x(t) then it's easy as you said. I can only find numerical solution for the integral in the question, I wonder if there is an analytic solution.

If you can help me state the problem more clearly, I appreciate it.

Comment: Ignacio, I'm afraid its you who does not understand zwim's comment. Elaborating his observation, try letting $X''(t)=x(t)$. Then your equation can be expressed as $X''(t) = c_1+k X(t)$.

Comment: Thank you Brian, how do you solve that simplification you are doing?If you can link a resource it's appreciated, I'm not math expert.
You have a variable on the other side which is the derivative of the variable on the right side. But how do you solve x(t) = 0? At least that is not the kind of equations I know how to solve.

Comment: I would suggest looking up the subject "ordinary differentials equations". This particular equation type of ODE is quite easily solved. You should be able to find everything you need in [this set of online notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IntroSecondOrder.aspx).

Comment: Thank, I will take a look to that. You should consider that not everyone has the same knowledge as you. It's obvious that I didn't know about differential equations and that's why I asked here.
zwim answer left me on the same spot, essentially you are assuming that the person that is asking has advanced math knowledge. The proper answer would be to explain about differential equations and I think that would actually be useful to people that is on a similar spot as me.

Comment: @achillehui from the definition $ x(0) = c $. I was asking for a general equation for the roots of x(t), such that $ x(t) = 0 $.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is finding a function that fits that behavior. This is what is called a differential equation. The differential equation can be obtained by deriving two times over t, then the equation becomes:

$ \ddot x= kx $

The function $ x(t) = e^{t\sqrt k} $ fits this equation. By deriving two times x(t) the result is:

$ \ddot x = \sqrt k\cdot \sqrt k\cdot e^{t\sqrt k} = k\cdot e^{t\sqrt k} $,

The function has no roots, but if $ k $  is negative:

$ i\sqrt -k = \sqrt k $,

$ k' = \sqrt -k $

The equation becomes:

$ k\cdot e^{i\cdot t\cdot k'} = k\cdot [cos(t\cdot k')+i\cdot sin(t\cdot k')]$

There are zeros in the real plane for $ t = \frac \pi {2\sqrt -k} (2j+1) ,j=0,1,2...$

Credit to @zwim and @brian for explaining and linking the resources.